# storm multilang seems had read from pipe but didn't clear the spout process's STDOUT

Tags: php, linux, pipe, multilingual, apache-storm

I'am using the storm's multilang throughing PHP. But it seems have some problem.
  Then my spout is a php script which read contents from a file.And in the beginning of the 4Mb content,which runs correctly.But the php process will blocks in the write(1,xxxx...,when i strace -p the php spout.
  But when i use 'cat' read from the /proc/pid/fd/1 which is the php process STDOUT. All of the content had been handle correctly in the bolt is still there.
  So, i doubt that spout hangs out when write(1,xxx , is because that the process's STDOUT buffer is full of contents. But how can i prevent this issue.
  My environment is
      Linux : 2.6.32_1-9-3-1 kernel.
             Java: 1.6.0_33
             Storm:0.8.2 or 0.8.1 
             PHP: 5.2

Comment: Please include code. Thanks.

Comment: my code is too many,but i don't know paste which part. The case is php is write to stdout and another php process has read this.But when i read from /proc/pid/fd/1,the original process's stdout still there..

Comment: possible duplicate of [storm multilang seems only process 4Mb spout, and then stop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25350900/storm-multilang-seems-only-process-4mb-spout-and-then-stop)