# storm multilang seems only process 4Mb spout, and then stop

Tags: php, deadlock, multilingual, processbuilder, apache-storm

I'am using the storm's multilang throughing PHP. But it seems have some problem.

Then my spout is a php script which read contents from a file.And in the beginning of the 4Mb content,which runs correctly.

But then php process will blocks in the write(1,xxxx...,when i strace -p the php spout. But the next bolt process is blocked in the read(0,

i doubt this is the storm's problem,but the question is why each time the spout analyse is 4Mb, and is it a java processBuild's deadlock? How to avoid it....

My environment is Linux : 2.6.32_1-9-3-1 kernel. Java: 1.6.0_33 Storm:0.8.2 or 0.8.1 PHP: 5.2

Comment: Try upgrading Storm. 0.8.x versions of Storm had a lot of zmq issues that would cause the process to hang. Most of our issues went away when we moved to 0.9

Comment: Thx,bridiver. I had the question's reason. Because i emit multiple times in a spout's nextTuple, i can only call emit once in a nextTuple. but this is wierd, the official document dosent specific this.